# Why does changing list[i] affect the list but changing element does not in `for i, element in inputList`?

Tags: python, list

In Python the following code will modify the output

```
def changeList(string):
    strList = list(string)
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == 'a':
            strList[i] = 'b'

    return "".join(strList)
```

```
print(changeList("ab"))
```

prints out "bb" as expected. However the following function:

```
def changeList(string):
    strList = list(string)
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        if char == 'a':
            char = 'b'

    return "".join(strList)
```

prints out "ab". Why does setting `char` work differently? I had thought that char was a pointer to string[i] but it looks like I'm misunderstand whats going on under the hood?

Comment: I suggest reading Ned Batchelders fantastic [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second example, you are reassigning the value of `char`. In the `for` loop, `char` is set as the character of the string (like 'a' or something). Then later, you're saying "ok now `char` is 'b'".

`char` is not linked to `strList[i]`, `char` is independent of the string you're moving through. If you wanted the second way to work, you'd have to add one more line `strList[i] = char`

Comment: That is a really helpful explanation, thank you

Answer (score 1):

In your first `for` loop, by accessing `strList[i]` you modify the item in the list, where as in the second loop the list item gets the name tag `char`. Then when you do `char = 'b'` the name tag is taken away from the list item and applied to `'b'`. The list item itself is not modified, so the list is returned unchanged.

Comment: "the list item is copied" isn't quite right. Assignment never copies data. You could say that the list item gets the name tag `char`. Then when you do `char = 'b'` the name tag is taken away from the list item and applied to `'b'`. The list item itself is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Matthias, edited my answer